# Retrieving Django LineStringField causes DjangoUnicodeDecodeError

Tags: mysql, django, geodjango

I have a GeoDjango model:

```
class RouteLeg(models.Model):
  """Models one 'leg' of a route. A leg is one linestring 
  and belongs to a route."""
  # the route which owns it
  route = models.ForeignKey(Route)

  # A line which represents this leg of the route
  line = models.LineStringField()

  def get_line(self):
    return self.line
```

I save a `RouteLeg` with a line string that looks like this:

```
LINESTRING (-3.1448364257812500 54.5469778189498768, -2.9031372070312500 54.4233245371087477)
```

And calling `.save()` does not cause any errors. When I go to retrieve the routeleg

```
print route.routeleg_set.all()[0].get_line()
```

I get:

```
DjangoUnicodeDecodeError at /route/1
`'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 17: invalid start byte. 
You passed in '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x02\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xa0(\t\xc0y\x03\x82^\x03FK@\x00\x00\x00\x00\xa09\x07\xc0\xfb<\x99\x7f/6`K@'
(<type 'str'>)
```

I've trawled SO for answers, most relate to template encoding. I believe that this error is specific to the database. I have tried clear-ing and syncdb-ing the DB, which is MySQL.

---

**Edit**
This turned out to be a trick question. The problem turned out to be with [Shapely](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Shapely). I was using the shapely.wkt.dumps function.

```
from shapely.geometry import shape
from shapely.wkt import dumps
s = shape(geoJson)
wkt = str(dumps(s))
```

But `dumps()` returns some thing that looks like a string, saved to the MySQL db okay, but could not be retrieved. The working code was:

```
from shapely.geometry import shape
s = shape(geoJson)
return s.wkt
```

Comment: I'm looking at the source code for `GeometryField` and there's no hint it is intended to be printed. It doesn't have a `str` nor `unicode` method. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Although it should use `Field`'s which does nothing more than returning app's and model's name. Can you provide more info about the error? Surrounding models and exception's full traceback?